# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 197 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]

Tags: ios, sqlite, tags, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have product table in database. Product table i have id & product_image column. Each image having id. I'm getting these id from database and taken to cat_imageidArray, Then getting images & taken to productimg_array. Assign the productimg_array image value to imgView1 (UIButton). I'm using [productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]. Here index is 0 to 7 or etc. But cat_imageidArray having value of 183,184,190 etc. When i click imgView1 button i'm getting these error [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 197 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]. I understood the problem is array value is not matching. How to assign the cat_imageidArray value to productimg_array index. Maybe then it will work.

```
const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image,order_by,description FROM product where cat_id = ?";

        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.

            if (sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, categoryId) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSLog(@"%s: bind failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                cat_iamgeId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                NSLog(@"cat_iamgeId is %ld",(long)cat_iamgeId);
                [cat_imageidArray addObject:@(cat_iamgeId)];

                product_image = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                NSLog(@"product_image is %@",product_image);
                [productimg_array addObject:product_image];                    
            }
        }


for (int i = 0; i<[productimg_array count]; i++ ) {

            NSLog(@"productimg_array_index %@", productimg_array[i]);
            imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];
            Width = Width + 20+(i*74);
            for (int i=0; i<[cat_imageidArray count]; i++){

               NSLog(@"index %@", cat_imageidArray[i]);
               tag=[[cat_imageidArray objectAtIndex:i]intValue];
               imgView1.tag=tag;
               NSLog(@"tag is %d",tag);
            }

            [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dbsofaClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

           [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];
       }        


imgView1 button click:

-(void)dbsofaClicked:(id)sender{

   NSLog(@"button %d is clicked.", [sender tag]);            
             mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];

    [mmageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

       [mmageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

    }];
```

NSLog productimg_array:

```
productimg_array (
"http://center.net/projects/View/images/img.png",
"http://center.net/projects/View/images/img1.png",
"http://center.net/projects/View/images/img2.png",
"http://center.net/projects/View/images/img3.png",
"http://center.net/projects/View/images/img4.png",
"http://center.net/projects/View/images/img5.png",
"http://center.net/projects/View/images/img6.png",
"http://center.net/projects/View/images/img7.png",
"http://center.net/projects/View/images/img8.png"
)
```

When i use singleTap the image i didn't get correct description from database value. that's why i need to set id instead of index

```
- (void)singleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)singletap {
  NSLog(@"singleTap1");
    UIView *view = singletap.view;
    switch (view.tag) {
        case 0:

            txtt=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];

            txtt.text=[descript_array objectAtIndex:0];

            txtt.editable=NO;

            NSLog(@"text is %@",txtt.text);

            [self.view addSubview:txtt];





            break;

        case 1:


            txtt1=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];

            txtt1.text=[descript_array objectAtIndex:1];

            NSLog(@"text1 is %@",txtt1.text);

            [self.view addSubview:txtt1];



            break;

        case 2:

            txtt2=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];

            txtt2.text=[descript_array objectAtIndex:2];

            NSLog(@"text2 is %@",txtt2.text);

            [self.view addSubview:txtt2];



            break;

        case 3:

            txtt3=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];

            txtt3.text=[descript_array objectAtIndex:3];

            NSLog(@"text is %@",txtt3.text);

            [self.view addSubview:txtt3];




            break;
```

Comment: Everything is okay with you db and productimg_array. Only thing your imgView1 buttin tag have greater value than your productimg_array.

Comment: Instead of taking two array you must need to take a class which contains Product_id and cat_id. Your have write the wrong logic and implement wrong data structure. So, first please Solve that one. Its crashing because you used wrong mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Remove inner for loop that solve your problem

```
for (int i = 0; i<[productimg_array count]; i++ ) {

        NSLog(@"productimg_array_index %@", productimg_array[i]);
        imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];
        Width = Width + 20+(i*74);
        //for (int i=0; i<[cat_imageidArray count]; i++){ **This line doesn't need**

           NSLog(@"index %@", cat_imageidArray[i]);
           tag=[[cat_imageidArray objectAtIndex:i]intValue];
           **Changed**//imgView1.tag=tag; 
           imgView1.tag = i;
           NSLog(@"tag is %d",tag);
        //}

        [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dbsofaClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

       [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];
   }
```

Comment: See the ans. You made a mistake on providing the tag value.

Comment: see the database table. I have cat_id column. cat_id having 3, 4, 52. each cat_id having id, product_image & description. If i click third cat_id it displays the images index 0 to 7. If i click the cat_id 4 it displays the product_image 0 to 3. but the problem is when  i get description it taking 0 to some index value. If cat_id 4 values taking cat_id 3 description value. Because index value? That's why i'm associate with id (cat_imageidArray)

Comment: can you come to chat?

Comment: I have changed the ans. So check first.

Comment: I don't want to set index value 0 to some value. I need to set id value instead of index. See the image. I have category sofa, table, etc. Sofa is cat_id 3 & table is cat_id 4 so on. If i click the sofa it displays the images then click table it displays the images. But when i click sofa it index value starting from 0 to so on, if i click table it index value start from 0 to so on. here index value coming same for sofa & table. this is my problem.

Comment: If you doesn't understand please let me know. I stuck with one week this issue.

Comment: Can you check my edited question .When i use single tap i'm getting decription value using objectAtIndex: .Here i got wrong description value because of index??